Laravel 10 use default email template using Symphony mailer
I wanted to convert the below code to symphony mailer using symphony mailer Transport. But I can't add the existing templete in symphony mailer without using twig concept.
Existing Code:
$data = array(.....);
$subject = "Test Email";
Mail::send('mail.invitation', $data, function($message)
{
    $message
        ->to($this->toEmail)
        ->from($this->fromEmail)
        ->subject($subject);
});

Similarly:
$transport = Transport::fromDsn(env('MAILER_DSN'));
$mailer = new Mailer($transport);
$data = array(.....);
$subject = "Test Email";
        
$email = (new Email())
    ->from($this->fromEmail)
    ->to($this->toEmail)
    ->priority(Email::PRIORITY_HIGH)
    ->subject($subject)
    ->text('Sending emails')
    ->html('mail.invitation', $data);

    $mailer->send($email);

Please help me and thanks in advance.
